# How can I change the oracle sql to mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

The following Oracle SQL is

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT ROWNUM AS rn, A.* FROM (
    SELECT ROWNUM, bno, title, content, b.regdate, viewcnt, user_name as userName
    FROM tbl_board b, tbl_member m
    ORDER BY bno DESC, b.regdate DESC) A)
WHERE rn BETWEEN '1' AND '10';
```

I want to change this SQL to MySQL. How can i do that? (i try to paging system)

Comment: Please add what you have attempted and researched to your post. Also, please take a look at: [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). thanks!

Comment: are you using mysql 8 ?

Comment: yes! im using mysql8

Comment: What version of Mysql are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct analogue to ROWNUM in MySQL. (*Update*: thanks to @Strawberry, Mysql 8 has ROW_NUMBER() function)
But you can emulate it via `variables` like:

```
SELECT t.*, 
       @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank
  FROM yourtable t, 
       (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

in your case, you should apply two variables for each level of sub-queries.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

Comment: @Strawberry thank you. So, it seems v8 has the required function. I'll leave my answer as-is for the visitors with older MySQL versions.

Comment: Note that your emulation would require an ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `limit`?

```
SELECT bno, title, content, b.regdate, viewcnt, user_name as userName
FROM tbl_board b CROSS JOIN
     tbl_member m
ORDER BY bno DESC, b.regdate DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

For paging you would add an `OFFSET` modifier.  For instance:

```
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

If you actually need the row numbers, then you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY bno, b.regdate) as rn
       bno, title, content, b.regdate, viewcnt, user_name as userName
FROM tbl_board b CROSS JOIN
     tbl_member m
ORDER BY bno DESC, b.regdate DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT top 10 m.ROWNUM, m.bno, m.title, m.content, b.regdate, m.viewcnt,        m.user_name
FROM tbl_board b, tbl_member m
ORDER BY m.bno DESC, b.regdate DESC;
```